# Check if the file was opened in C

Tags: c, function, file

I am trying to write a function to check if the file has been opened and if not, open it. The file is defined in main and is passed to the function as an argument. The code works, but when I try to add something to main function (as simple as int i;), the program crashes and the error message is: **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)** in the line with "if (*subor==NULL) {" I therefore suppose there's a problem with the way file is stored.

Here's my code:

```
int funkcia_v (FILE **subor) {
    if (*subor==NULL) {
        printf("File has not been opened yet.\n");
        *subor = fopen("pathtothefile.txt","r");
        if (*subor==NULL) {
            printf("File not opened.\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("File already opened.\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char c;
    //if i type int i; here, the program crashes
    FILE* subor;
    
    printf("Start the function.\n");
    c = getchar();
    
    while (1) {
        if (c=='v') {
            funkcia_v(subor);
        }
        else if (c=='k') {
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Unknown key, try again.");
            printf("\n");
        }
        fflush(stdin);
        c = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts on what this could be?

Comment: First problem: Missing headers so you get implicit function types. I assume that is a paste error. Next problem: Turn on the compiler warnings.The compiler will tell you exactly what is wrong. Hell, with gcc you don't even need to turn on anything. The error is so big it warns about it per default.

Comment: The thing is the compiler (Xcode) doesn't warn me about anything in the significant line.

Comment: The file pointer is not initialized in `main()`.  You've no idea what it points at.  You can initialize it to NULL; you can assign a value from `fopen()`.  You can't tell by just looking at it whether it is a valid non-null pointer or just garbage.

Comment: @Adam There should be a BIG FAT UGLY warning that you are passing a `FILE *` to a function expecting a `FILE **`.

Comment: PS: don't forget to close the file at the end IF it is opened.

Comment: Aside: `fflush()` on a stream opened for input is undefined.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When I try FILE *subor = NULL;, it crashes even faster with the same error on the same line.

Comment: If Xcode does not give warnings on this, that is a huge black eye for Xcode.

Comment: Did you fix the function call?  It sounds like you didn't.  You could protect your function against misuse by checking `if (subor == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, “%s(): passed thanks pointer as argument\n”, __func_\); short(); }` or thereabouts.  Or: `assert(subor != NULL);` but that check depends on you not compiling with `-DNDEBUG` among the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, combining all the constructive comments above,
we have this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int funkcia_v (FILE **subor) {
    if (*subor==NULL) {
        printf("File has not been opened yet.\n");
        *subor = fopen("pathtothefile.txt","r");
        if (*subor==NULL) {
            printf("File not opened.\n");
        }
        else printf("File just opened.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("File already opened.\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char c;
    int i; // doesn't crash
    FILE* subor = NULL;
    
    printf("Start the function.\n");
    c = getchar();
    
    while (1) {
        if (c=='v') {
            funkcia_v(&subor);
        }
        else if (c=='k') {
            break;
        }
        else if (c!=10) {
            printf("Unknown key %c, try again.",c);
            printf("\n");
        }
        c = getchar();
    }

    if (subor!=NULL) fclose (subor);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that it passes a pointer of the file pointer to the function.

Comment: And what is the answer to the question "Any thoughts on what this could be?"?

Comment: You missed the `subor == NULL` check before `*subor`.

Comment: Additionally I would write a funkcia_close(&subor) that a) calls `fclose()` as needed and b) sets the FILE* back to `NULL` so the file is marked as not yet opened again.